# Sufficient conditions for Kan extension's to exist and be flat/coflat and exist

Tags: category-theory

I'm very new to category theory and a little confused about how to proceed with the following problem any help is welcome!

Suppose $F:A \to B$ is a flat and coflat functor, that is; it preserves limits and colimits that exist.
Let $p:A \to A'$ be an equivalence of categories.

When do the right and left Kan extension of $F$ along $p$ exist? And why?

When are the right and left Kan extension flat and coflat? And why?

Comment: It is straight forward to check that $F p^{-1}$ is the left/right Kan extension (where $p^{-1}$ is quasi-inverse to $p$).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really want the left and right Kan extension to be equal, so I've made a mistake in presuming that $p$ is an equivalence - it is in fact only faithful and essentially surjective. I doubt however this will be enough for the existence of Kan extensions. Regardless I am more interested in a rough proof that the Kan extension is flat and coflat so I will leave the question unedited.

Comment: Well, equivalences preserve any property you like.